# My touchpad doesn´t work properly

Tags: 14.04, dual-boot, mouse, touchpad, focaltech

I have a Laptop with dual boot Windows 8.1 and Ubuntu 14.04. My computer is an ASUS X552L. My problem is that my touchpad is crazy. I can't use it for anything because it doesn't click or move. I only can work with external mouse and every time I start the session have to enter the command:

```
sudo modprobe -r psmouse
```

Because if don't do that the mouse starts to move to the left all by itself.

`xinput` output:

```
 Virtual core pointer                       id=2    [master pointer  (3)]
|   ↳ Virtual core XTEST pointer                id=4    [slave  pointer  (2)]
|   ↳ USB OPTICAL MOUSE                         id=9    [slave  pointer  (2)]
| Virtual core keyboard                     id=3    [master keyboard (2)]
    ↳ Virtual core XTEST keyboard               id=5    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Power Button                              id=6    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Video Bus                                 id=7    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Sleep Button                              id=8    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ USB Camera                                id=10   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Asus WMI hotkeys                          id=11   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ AT Translated Set 2 keyboard              id=12   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ AT Raw Set 2 keyboard
```

`uname -r` output:

```
3.16.0-45-generic
```

`dmesg | grep pnp` output:

```
[    0.252003] pnp: PnP ACPI init
[    0.252450] pnp 00:02: Plug and Play ACPI device, IDs PNP0b00 (active)
[    0.252688] pnp 00:06: Plug and Play ACPI device, IDs FLT0101 SYN0a00 SYN0002 PNP0f03 PNP0f13 PNP0f12 (active)
[    0.252732] pnp 00:07: Plug and Play ACPI device, IDs ATK3001 PNP030b (active)
[    0.253885] pnp: PnP ACPI: found 11 devices
```

*Can anyone help me to fix it?*

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add output of `xinput && uname -r && dmesg | grep pnp` terminal command.

Comment: And what about the rest of commands? And also run `sudo modprobe psmouse` first. Or run it after reboot.

Comment: I start my pc and I selec go to Ubuntu, then I write my pass, afther that I must introduce the comand sudo modprobe -r psmouse and then my mouse works perfecly. But I don´t introduce any other comand

Comment: Please add also output of `uname -r` and `dmesg | grep pnp`.

Comment: Please also add output of `dkms status`.

Answer (score 1):

You have a Focaltech touchpad. You can fix it this way. Run in terminal:

```
sudo apt-get install linux-generic-lts-vivid
```

reboot.

Then run

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:hanipouspilot/focaltech-dkms
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install focaltech-dkms
```

But it looks like you tried to install a wrong driver. That's why your touchpad is not detected at all.

**UPDATE:** These touchpads are now supported by the 4.2 kernels.
The kernel can be installed by

```
sudo apt-get install linux-generic-lts-wily
```

The Focaltech driver from the PPA should be removed.

Comment: solved!!

thank you very much  for all you are incredible!

Comment: @David thanking is done by upvoting & ticking the answer in SE